# org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread with tx:advise

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using spring 3.2 with hibernate 4. I want to use spring to control the transactions.
However with the configuration mentioned below I get the

'Servlet.service() for servlet spring threw exception: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread'

exception:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="serviceMethods"
        expression="execution(* com.locator.service.impl.ServiceTypeService.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="serviceMethods" />
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="hbTransactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="hbSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>../spring/model/ServiceType.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="hbTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hbSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="serviceTypeService" class="com.locator.service.impl.ServiceTypeService">
    <property name="serviceTypeDao" ref="serviceTypeDao"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="serviceTypeDao" class="com.locator.dao.impl.ServiceTypeDao">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hbSessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

The code for the Dao layer and the Service is as follows:

```
public class ServiceTypeDao implements IServiceTypeDao{

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ServiceTypeDao.class);

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public ServiceType findById(int id) {
        log.debug("getting ServiceType instance with id: " + id);
        try {
            Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            ServiceType instance = (ServiceType)  session.get("com.locator.model.ServiceType", id);
            if (instance == null) {
                log.debug("get successful, no instance found");
            } else {
                log.debug("get successful, instance found");
            }

            instance.setName(instance.getName()+"0");
            session.saveOrUpdate(instance);

            return instance;
        }catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("get failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
}


public class ServiceTypeService implements IServiceTypeService{

    private ServiceTypeDao serviceTypeDao;

    public void setServiceTypeDao(ServiceTypeDao serviceTypeDao){
        this.serviceTypeDao = serviceTypeDao;
    }

    public ServiceType getServiceTypeById(int id){
        return serviceTypeDao.findById(id);
    }
}
```

Replacing getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession() with getSessionFactory().openSession() will resolve the above issue however, it will mean that the developer will then be responsible for the session open/close rather than spring. Therefore, please advise how this can be resolved using spring.

Comment: Your tx:advice matches all the service methods, so they are transactional. You have to call the dao method from the service to get your transaction managed by spring. findById in the dao is not transactional by itself. How do you execute it?

Comment: The Service class invokes the Dao. I have shared the code for the Service above as well.

Comment: Just to make sure, what happens if you remove the tx:advice stuff, and actuallt place a `@Transactional("hbTransactionManager")` on the `ServiceTypeService` class?

Comment: @geoand I bet it fixed his problem. I don't know why he was trying to manually do what `@Transactional` does anyway....

Comment: @JamesMassey There is a good chance that it worked. Let's hope we will find out :)

Comment: @Transactional did not fix this problem. I had already tried it before posting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. It was occurring due to the following problems:

1. The Service class had not been Auto wired into the controller i.e. the @Autowired annotation was missing.
2. The configuration for the web.xml had to be modified with the listener class 'org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener' and the context-param was added.